# PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> is getting executed for the second time

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to make an application where user current place will be messaged to predefined number. I have implemented ShakeDetector library. Everything is working fine but I am getting the place name for the second time when I am shaking the device. [Please see the screenshots]
I put a debug point on the lines on PendingResult part.
For the first time the "for loop" is not executing but when I am shaking it for the second time the for loop is executing and I am getting the places. Whats wrong? Does PendingResult work as asynctask in android?

**PS:** I faced the similar problem while I was working with Google Fit API.the PendingResult was getting executed when I am returning to previous activity by pressing back button.I resolved the issue by creating different fragments and providing single GoogleApiClient to each of them.But as you can guess there is no scope of this here. What should I do plz help.

[image: first time run]

[image: second time run when I am getting the places]

here is my code of the PhoneService.java where everything is happening.

```
public class PhoneService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
String place="";
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ShakeDetector.create(this, new ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnShake() {
            try{

                Toast.makeText(PhoneService.this,"Shake Detected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                buildApiClient();

            }catch (SecurityException e){

            }
        }
    });
    ShakeDetector.updateConfiguration(3f, 4);
    ShakeDetector.start();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ShakeDetector.stop();
}

public void buildApiClient(){
    googleApiClient= new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(PhoneService.this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(PhoneService.this)
            .build();
    googleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(PhoneService.this,"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try{
            if(googleApiClient.isConnected()){
                PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                        .getCurrentPlace(googleApiClient, null);
                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                        for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                            place=placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName()+"";
                            Log.d("PLACE",place);
                        }
                        likelyPlaces.release();
                        try{
                            SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
                            smsManager.sendTextMessage("7098027655",null,"I am here at "+place+".Please pick me up.",null,null);

                        }catch (SecurityException e){

                        }
                    }
                });

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:7098027655"));
                callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){

        }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(PhoneService.this,"Connection Suspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(PhoneService.this,"Connection Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're creating and connecting a brand new `GoogleApiClient` every time the user shakes the device. You might have more luck creating and connecting the client once in the service's `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I moved the buildApiClient() function to onCreate() and moved the place detection code to onShake() but it's still not working.